# Use two SSH ports, but open only one?

Tags: iptables, sshd

My `iptables.conf` looks roughly like this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 65000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

My `sshd_config` looks like this:

```
Port 22
Port 65000
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
```

My goal is to open only port 65000 to outside world, while I have port 22 opened to my LAN.

I tested this setup using [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/) on port `65000` and I can't connect to my machine at all, unless I add the following rule:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I can connect at port 65000.

What is going on? Why did I have to open port 22 to be able to connect on port 65000?

As requested, here is my full configuration:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       5.10.83.0/25         0.0.0.0/0           
 1040  146K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110
   11   640 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    1    40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:60000:60020
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:60000:60020
    3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:65000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:65001
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:65011
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8888 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
  735 67148 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       46.238.126.0/23      0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       78.10.202.145        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       109.173.223.100      0.0.0.0/0           
 1274  166K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1409  219K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:8888 state ESTABLISHED
```

NAT:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: You should not have to do that. Something else is going on. Can you edit your question to include a full dump of your `iptables` rules (`iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`), particularly any rules about `ESTABLISHED` connections (which you no doubt need)?

Comment: Added requested logs.

Comment: Additionally, I'm configuring the firewall through SSH on port 22, but I'm not sure how this could affect connectivity on port 65000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my router was set up to forward some high ports to the internal SSH port - so basically the problem was caused by some ancient configuration leftovers.

How stupid.